# How send the json object in parameter while navigating screen using kendo UI

Tags: ios, angularjs, kendo-mobile

I am using Kendo UI- AngularJS, and we have created the iOS mobile application which contains multiple screens(html pages) and for navigating from one html to another html we use "kendo.mobile.application.navigate(test.html);".

We want to pass the JSON object for test.html screen. JSON object contain array of objects. How to pass it?

I know if we want to pass one parameter then we can pass like "kendo.mobile.application.navigate(test.html?name='testName');", But we want to pass the JSON object. How do we achieve it?

Comment: you can `JSON.stringify()` the object, then pass it as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

You can first stringify your object then pass it as a parameter, for example:

```
var my_object = {};
my_object.title = "hello";
my_object.price = "15"
window.location.href = "test.html?response=" + JSON.stringify(my_object);
```

And on the detailed view you can receive this object like this:

```
//onShow event
function fooShow(e) {
var my_params = JSON.parse(e.view.params.response)
console.log(my_params) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass it in URL because of [maximum length limitation of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/1849455)

Instead pass plain JSON object in [localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2010948/1849455)